# Data not showing in power bi report

Tags: data-warehouse, microsoft-fabric

I am working on an ETL project in Microsoft Fabric. The project involves sending files from a SharePoint folder to a data warehouse through a Data Flow Gen 2. The data flows are updating correctly, and the data appears in the data warehouse. The problem is, when i press the button  'new report',in the warehouse, the data that appears in the power BI report is not the most recent data, even though this refreshed data is in the data warehouse tables. Can anyone solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

power bi has two ways of loading data a) Imports b)DirectQuery, I think if it is set to Imports then you have to schedule the refresh or you can also manually refresh it but it would not automatically refresh it self.